# CentOS volume group out of disk space

Tags: centos, disk-volume

I am very inexperienced in Linux server administration and I got suck... I have a VM running under CentOS centos-release-7-6.1810.2.el7.centos.x86_64. On this VM I am running a test installation of an ActiveMQ-InfluxDB-Grafana stack.

Now my system ran out of disk space. "df" shows the follwing:

```
/dev/mapper/vg_main-root      16766976 15605268   1161708  94% /
devtmpfs                       8116348        0   8116348   0% /dev
tmpfs                          8133376        0   8133376   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                          8133376   778780   7354596  10% /run
tmpfs                          8133376        0   8133376   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1                      1007896   189228    767468  20% /boot
tmpfs                          1626676       12   1626664   1% /run/user/42
tmpfs                          1626676        4   1626672   1% /run/user/0
/dev/mapper/vg_main-influxdb  61856248    32992  61823256   1% /var/lib/influxdb/data
```

This is the state after having deleted all the InfluxDB-files, which consumed 20G on volume-group vg_main_influxdb. I cleaned as well temporary files on vg_main-root, which brought down the disk usage from 100% to the 94% you see here.

Command vgs shows:

```
  VG      #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize   VFree
  vg_main   1   3   0 wz--n- <79.02g    0
```

furthermore we have

```
[root@vmla032 /]# du -h --max-depth=1
184M    ./boot
0       ./dev
0       ./proc
761M    ./run
0       ./sys
42M     ./etc
120M    ./root
1.1G    ./var
36K     ./tmp
4.2G    ./usr
360K    ./home
0       ./mnt
747M    ./opt
0       ./srv
7.0G    .
```

Result of pvdisplay

```
[root@vmla032 /]# pvdisplay
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sda2
  VG Name               vg_main
  PV Size               79.02 GiB / not usable 3.00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes (but full)
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              20229
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          20229
```

Another symptom is that vg_main-root gets filled with data by some process and runs out of disk space. For example log data seems to go there as disk space got freed whe I deleted these files.

How do I get more space? How do I find out which processes clog vg_main-root?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the community!

Your volume group `vg_main` has two logical volumes in it. They are called `influxdb` and `root`. Since they are on the same volume group and the one you want to grow is root, this is actually pretty easy. You can use the `lvresize` tool to shrink the `influxdb` volume so you can add that to the `root` volume. 
You will required downtime though because we have to take influxdb offline.

Here is an example of what you might do after stopping any service dependent on the influxdb mount.

```
sudo -i #(become root)
umount /var/lib/influxdb/data
lvresize --resizefs --size -10G /dev/mapper/vg_main-influxdb
lvresize --resizefs --size +10G /dev/mapper/vg_main-root
mount /var/lib/influxdb/data
```

Then you should be able to check `df -h` for the results and start your services back up.

Comment: @flickery: your answer cured the problem, but only in a symptomatic way. Still I am not clear, why vg_main-root runs out of disk space. Where does the data come from? Why can I increase free space on root when deleting e.g. log files. How do I see which locations/files consume space in root?

Comment: That's a huge topic. Install `ncdu` (or use the `du` command which is harder to work with) and it'll help show you where your largest amount of storage is taken up. Usually /var/log is where you're going to deal with that and it may mean you need to configure some log rotation. There is a program called `logrotate` which you can configure to rotate logs. One thing to consider is that even after you delete a file, if it is being held open it isn't actually deleted yet. Perhaps a process is writing to it consistently (often true of logs). Use `lsof` to find these or restart the processes.